# Java for Android: Inflating XML Layouts, TextView's overlapping

Tags: java, android, android-layout

So here's my deal. I have an app that connects to a PHP site that gets JSON data and parses it out. The JSON parsing works perfectly so no need to look to deep into that. I need to allow for an infinite amount of items from the PHP site so I'm creating a loop to inflate an XML file for each item. My problem is that the TextView items lblShared and lblSaid are overlapping lblQuote. They are suppose to be aligning below lblQuote. I'll post the basics of my source please just request more if needed.

```
LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myMainLayout);
LayoutInflater linflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View myView = linflater.inflate(R.layout.myviews, null);
TextView tvQuote = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.lblQuote);
//Set an id to know which quote is in use
tvQuote.setId(i);
TextView tvShared = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.lblShared);
TextView tvSaid = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.lblSaid);

//Change name dynamically
tvQuote.setText((strQuote).toString());
tvShared.setText(("Shared by: " + strShared).toString());
tvSaid.setText(("Said by: " + strSaid).toString());
l.addView(myView);
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:id="@+id/myMainLayout" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:text="Title" 
        android:id="@+id/lblTitle" 
        android:textSize="16px" 
        android:padding="5px" 
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

myviews.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/lblQuote" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/lblShared" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/lblQuote"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/lblSaid" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/lblQuote"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use another LinearLayout if you are going to stack them like that..?

Relative is not meant to stacking elements on-top of each other by design.